# Trying to run Konsole from XMing (Windows) fails

Tags: linux, windows, xorg, kde, dbus

Connecting from XMing latest running on a Windows 7 laptop to an Ubuntu 14.04 server running KDE.

I get the following error:

```
cpatti@hab: ~
$ konsole                                                                                                                                           [21:05:46]
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave.
unnamed app(15587): KUniqueApplication: Cannot find the D-Bus session server:  "Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-uMb0BMC1R6: Connection refused" 

unnamed app(15586): KUniqueApplication: Pipe closed unexpectedly.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25998/how-do-i-prevent-ssh-remote-login-from-breaking-dbus

Turns out the answer is to put 'dbus-launch konsole' in the "Program to Run" box rather than just Konsole.

Answer (score 1):

You need dbus server to run konsole, Install the package with this command:

```
apt-get install dbus
```

and try again to run konsole

Comment: You're very close, but the system already had dbus installed.  The issue is that you have to run konsole from the dbus context.  See my answer above for what actually worked :)

Answer (score 1):

So, the resolution for me was, to dump Xming all together and replace it with [Xpra](http://xpra.org). I played around with the binary packages that come with Ubuntu but was out of luck. To get things working correctly, I actually downloaded the binaries (version 0.15.10) from http://xpra.org/#download as I was recommended bythe winswitch [mailing list](http://lists.devloop.org.uk/mailman/listinfo/shifter-users)(linked from the [Xpra.org](http://Xpra.org). site)

Answer (score 0):

a better answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188877/32769 
(it checks existing dbus, if not launch a new one, and make ssh session know about it.
requires bash, dbus and systemd to work, but that should be the case of a system sunning dbus)